# MIT code interfacing GPL3 library,

Tags: licensing, license-notice

I have a Python module, pygalmesh ([Github](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh), [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pygalmesh/)), published under the *MIT* license. It essentially interfaces a part of [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) which is published under the [GPL3](https://www.cgal.org/license.html) and uses other pieces of software with different licenses (e.g., Eigen with MPL2). I understand that this is fine since [MIT is GPL-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License). **Q:** Is that correct?

To install pygalmesh, the user first has to download and install CGAL (e.g., via [Debian/Ubuntu](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libcgal-dev)) and Eigen, and then

```
pip install pygalmesh
```

The resulting binary library `_pygalmesh.so` contains both compiled pygalmesh, Eigen, CGAL code (and more, like pybind11). I believe the user then has to adhere to all restrictions induced by those licenses, meaning, for example, she cannot include this library into another piece of software and *not* publish the code.

The command

```
pip show pygalmesh
```

however simply shows *MIT* as license as defined [here](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/blob/master/setup.cfg#L10). My concern is that the user might be mislead into thinking that `_pygalmesh.so` is completely *MIT* as well. **Q:** Is it correct to say pygalmesh is *MIT* or should it rather say *MIT + GPL3* or  *MIT + GPL3 + MPL2* or *Mixed* or something entirely different?

Comment: It is correct to state that your source code is MIT-licensed. But as a courtesy to users, I'd note in your Readme that you have GPL dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In no way does GPL forbid mangling the code whichever way you fancy. It places conditions on *distribution*.

In this case, the licenses allow doing the combining, no problem. You are right (partially) in that you *can't* distribute the combination, as you would have to distribute the whole hairball under GPL, and at least you can't do that for the closed part.

Comment: But can I say "MIT" for pygalmesh on https://pypi.org/project/pygalmesh/? The _code_ is MIT alright, but if the user installs from there, the .so will also contain GPL code.